# Jenkins - communicate from Docker agent to other Docker containers

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, jenkins

I am running a Jenkins job using a buildkite/puppeteer Docker agent. As I understand it, this creates a container from this image and runs the job inside it. The job pulls a React frontend and Express backend app from their respective repos, installs their dependencies, starts them and runs an `npm` script to kick off CodeceptJS / Puppeteer end to end tests, which reside in the front end repo.

Before the tests are run I need to populate a MongoDB instance with test data (old test data should be deleted) and index an Elasticsearch instance (old index should be deleted). To do this locally, I have a MongoDB and Elasticsearch container running, and a bash script does the necessaries before I run the tests by running `docker` commands and `curl` requests; however, I'm having difficulty understanding how I can do this in Jenkins. The Jenkins host machine has Docker containers for Mongo and Elasticsearch running, but the Jenkins job is unable to communicate with them - logs show that the docker command is not found, and curl requests to the ES container fail. Here is what my Jenkins pipeline code looks like - I have had to redact some information:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'buildkite/puppeteer'
            args '--net=[redacted]_ci --add-host=[redacted]:127.0.0.1'
        }
    }

    environment {
        HOME = "${env.WORKSPACE}"
        MONGO_HOST = "[redacted]_mongo"
        ELASTIC_HOST = "[redacted]_elastic"
        API_ROOT_URL = "http://[redacted]:9001"
    }

    stages {
        stage('Clone repositories') {
            parallel {
                stage('pull from [react repo]') {
                    steps {
                        dir('[react folder]') {
                            git url: '[redacted]', branch: [redacted], credentialsId: 'global_github'
                        }
                    }
                }

                stage('pull from [backend repo]') {
                    steps {
                        dir('[backend folder]') {
                            git url: '[redacted]', branch: [redacted], credentialsId: 'global_github'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Install npm dependencies') {
            parallel {
                stage('npm ci (react app)') {
                    steps {
                        dir('[react folder]') {
                            sh 'npm ci' // clean-install
                            //sh 'npm install'
                        }
                    }
                }

                stage('npm ci (api app)') {
                    steps {
                        dir('[backend folder]') {
                            sh 'npm ci' // clean-install
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Start web servers') {
            parallel {
                stage('Start API server') {
                    steps {
                        dir('[backend folder]') {
                            sh 'cp server/config/environment/secrets.ci.js server/config/environment/secrets.js'
                            sh 'echo $PATH'
                            sh 'ls -la /usr/bin'
                            sh 'nohup npm run serve &' // Would run script here also to populate DB and create ES index
                        }
                    }
                }
                stage('Start React server') {
                    steps {
                        dir('[react folder]') {
                            sh 'nohup npm start &'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Wait for servers to be ready') {
            options {
                timeout(time: 5, unit: 'MINUTES')
            }

            parallel {
                stage('Wait for API server') {
                    steps {
                        sh 'while ! curl http://[redacted]:9001; do sleep 1; done'
                    }
                }
                stage('Wait for React server') {
                    steps {
                        sh 'while ! curl http://[redacted]:3000; do sleep 1; done'
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Run acceptance tests') {
            steps {
                dir('[react folder]') {
                    //sh 'npm run e2e' // Script to run CodeceptJS / Puppeteer tests
                    sh 'docker ps' // Failure - docker command not found
                    sh 'echo skipping tests'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to communicate with host Docker and other containers to do what I need to or would it be better to climb out of the rabbit hole and start again with a different approach?

Answer (score 1):

you can specify a different agent per stage. A solution (or part of it) would be to declare agent master just before the steps of the stage('Run acceptance tests')